# Node Twitter Streaming API 401 when passing 'follow' parameter

Tags: node.js, twitter, twitter-streaming-api

I'm trying to stream the timeline of another user.

I've set up an app and got all the creds, but I keep getting a `401`. What am I doing wrong?

```
import Twitter from 'twitter';
import socketIO from 'socket.io';
import streamHandler from './../util/streamHandler';
import http from 'http';

export default function(app, serverConfig) {
  const server = http.createServer(app);
  const io = socketIO(server);


  const twit = new Twitter(serverConfig.twitter);


  twit.stream('statuses/filter', {
    follow: ['76633197'],
  }, (stream) => {

    stream.on('data', (tweet) => {
      console.log('data');
      console.log(tweet.text);
    });

    stream.on('error', (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  });

  return server;
}
```

`serverConfig.twitter` looks like:

```
{
  consumer_key: <redacted>,
  consumer_secret: <redacted>,
  access_token_key: <redacted>,
  access_token_secret: <redacted>
}
```

UPDATE: This only happens when I `follow`. If I pass `{track: 'javascript'}` as the parameter it works fine...

Comment: Hi, have you ever resolved this? Having the same issue now.

Comment: Did any of you ever figure this out?